# Recover merge state of a git rebase

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm in the middle of a git rebase with the following history:

```
edit eac4848
join 84945e5
done ed60fdd
done 1c6399a
```

As you can see, commits `1c6399a` and `ed60fdd` are done and git is now trying to apply commit `84945e5` but there are some conflicts. This is expected and I just have to resolve the conflicts and move on.

Unfortunately, I called `git reset --hard` and now my commit is gone:

```
edit eac4848
gone 84945e5
done ed60fdd
done 1c6399a
```

What command should I use to recover my working directory in the initial merge conflict situation?

I tried calling the following command:

```
$ git merge --squash --ff 84945e5
```

This kind of works but it seems that the merge does not take into account file renames.

Comment: Note that you can always start over with `git rebase --abort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
git cherry-pick 84945e5
```

This will just repeat what `git rebase` already did that caused the merge conflicts in the first place.

If all else fails and you get in a complete snarl, you can start over with

```
git rebase --abort
```

Now repeat the same steps for the rebase and avoid making the same mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was hidden in the [`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-rebase--interactive.sh#L408) command source code (which is written in shell).

The next commit needs just to be cherry picked using the command:

```
$ git cherry-pick <NEXT_COMMIT>
```